# What are presents for?

Tags: hammerwatch

I occasionally find presents in hammerwatch and at first I thought it was a extra life or coins or something but then figured out it doesn't really do much, what are presents for? They aren't difficult to find so I assume they aren't that important.

Comment: This game is extremely good. Was also wondering this for quite a while +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [1.2 Patch Notes](http://hammerwatch.com/forum/index.php?topic=1811.0), obtaining 24 presents earns you an achievement:

> Christmas 2013 - Find 24 Christmas presents before, well, when we choose to end it.

Other than that, AFAIK they serve no purpose.

Comment: Wow seriously? That's.... That's kinda pointless......